# Find dead doc link in Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a database and also doc links, I am trying to access those doc link through web. I have found the method appendDocLink in the help. Looked through all the NotesRichTextItem, Document and NotesDocument properties and methods, but there's nothing to check dead link.

What I am trying to do is get all the doclinks in lotus script, and then check to see if they lead to an existing doc or if its a dead link. If yes then will send a mail to the admin about the dead link. All these things I want to happen using a schedule agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse the `NotesRichTextItem` using `NotesRichTextNavigator` and find the elements of type `NotesRichTextDocLink`.

```
Dim rti As NotesRichTextItem
Dim rtnav As NotesRichTextNavigator
Dim rtlink As NotesRichTextDocLink

Set rti = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
Set rtnav = rti.CreateNavigator

If Not rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_DOCLINK) Then
    Messagebox "No doclinks in Body item",, "No doclinks"
    Exit Sub
End If

Do
    Set rtlink = rtnav.GetElement

    'Use rtlink.DocUNID to get document UNID and try to fetch the document

Loop While rtnav.FindNextElement
```

I am not sure whether creating new `NotesDocument` object from `rtlink.DocUNID` would result in error or `NOTHING` (in case document with that UNID is not present). You will have to check that yourself.

*The above code snippet has been taken from [here](http://goo.gl/GjOiFO) and modified for this answer.*